# PIC16f873a blinking led program in C

Tags: pic

I am working on pic16f873a i used mikroC pro (free version) and tried to make a blinking LED program but it didn't worked, i tried MPLAB X IDE with XC 8 compiler , both the program build succesfully but nothing really happens on the IC , need help. I followed every steps carefully watching videos of 16f877a and make the right changes but still not working,
I am looking for a code in c for blinking LED of PIC16f873a

Comment: Please read or review "asking a question" [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void main(void) 
{
TRISA.B0 = 0;
while(1)
{
PORTA.B0 = 1;
delay_ms(500);
PORTA.B0 = 0;
delay_ms(500);
}
}
```

*Led blinking program for picf16873a to pin RAO.

*use 20.000 MHz crystal.

*Do not use pF capacitor Crystal,(I used pF capacitors with crystal but didn't worked)

*make sure that MClr pin is connected to vdd with 10 k resistor.

*make sure that all vdd and vss are connected properly.

*MCU clock  10.000 MHz

*Programmed in mikroC and burned by PICKIT2